# Sending png file via socket in Python

Tags: python, sockets, png, send

I'm using python version 2.7.9 and i try to send png file.
But something strange happens..i using sockets and sends a post request(or kind of).
I send the request to the server from the client,then i prints the length of the request received on the server, for example, the length is:1051.

Then I do a regex to take the png file data, and then prints the length, and the length is 2632, that he larger than the response?!

I think the problem is that it's actually write the content, but not the right of representation, I tried different things but they did not work, so I ask here how to solve this problem.

Server source code:

```
import socket
import re

server = socket.socket()
server.bind(('0.0.0.0',8080))

while True:
    server.listen(2)
    (client, client_addr) = server.accept()
    print 'IP :',client_addr

    res = client.recv(0xfffffff)
    print len(res)

    #get file name
    file_name = res.split('&')[0]
    file_name = str(file_name.split('=')[1])
    print repr(res)

    #get the data of the file
    raw_img = str(re.findall("&photo_data=(.*)" ,res ,re.DOTALL))

    print "File name:" + file_name
    print "Size:" + str(len(raw_img))
    with open(file_name, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(raw_img)

    print "Done"
```

Client source code:

```
import socket

client = socket.socket()
client.connect(('127.0.0.1',8080))

raw_data = open('test.png', 'rb').read()
save_file_name = raw_input("Enter the file name:")
print len(raw_data)

output = 'POST /upload HTTP/1.1\r\n'
output += 'Content-Length:' + str(len(raw_data)) + str(len(save_file_name)) + '\r\n\r\n'
output += 'file_name=' + save_file_name + '&'
output += 'photo_data=' + raw_data
print len(output)

client.send(output)
client.close()
```

Comment: The quesstion is why do you use raw sockets? There are libraries that will take care of it for you. Especially since you seem to have embraced rest-like format you could just use bottle as rest server and requests as the client.

Comment: It's part of the learning networks, so at the moment I do not use prepared libraries..

Comment: Are you saying the server receives less data than expected? Unlike a file, a socket returns smaller chunks of data so `res = client.recv(0xfffffff)` may not be the full png. Keep reading the socket in a loop until it reurns a zero length string.

Comment: No, but after the filtering of the data, it becomes larger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should use `while True` to receive the full data:

```
res = ''
while True:
    data = client.recv(1024)
    if not data:
        break
    res += data
print len(res)
```

Then, `re.findall` actually returns an array, not a string. So you should do this:

```
r = re.findall("&photo_data=(.*)" ,res ,re.DOTALL)
raw_img = str(r[0])
```

Now it works fine.

---

Why doesn't the code before work? Let's say we have a list:

```
r = ['\x45']
```

The data in `raw_img` part is basically like this. If we brutely convert this list to a str, we have:

```
print len(str[r]))  # ['E'], 5
```

Actually, what we need is r[0]:

```
print len(str[r[0])) # 1
```

That's why the size of the file became larger.